# Javascript -sort array based on another javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, compare

I have one javascript array and one object . Need help to sort javascript object keys based on the order number in another array

In subgroup array , I have name , order number. Need to sort Offerings keys based on that order number

```
const subgroup = [
        {
            "code": "6748",
            "name": "test123",
            "orderNumber": "0"
        },
        {
            "code": "1234",
            "name": "customdata",
            "orderNumber": "1"
        }
    ]

 const offerings = {
        "customdata" : [
    {
        "code": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
      }
    ],
        "test123" : [
    {
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
      }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Comment: Your title says "sort array", but then your code shows a plain object to be sorted (not an array). When you need a specific order, don't use a plain object, but an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you. I've added some comments in the code that should hopefully do an okay job of explaining what is happening.

```js
var subgroup = [{
    "code": "6748",
    "name": "test123",
    "orderNumber": "0"
  }, {
    "code": "1234",
    "name": "customdata",
    "orderNumber": "1"
  }];

var offerings = {
    "customdata": [{
        "code": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
    }],
    "test123": [{
        "brand": "Audi",
        "color": "black"
    }]
}

function sortObjectFromArray(refArray, sortObject, orderKey = 'order', linkKey = 'key') {
  // Get copy of refArray
  let reference = refArray.slice();

  // Sort sortObject [ into an array at this point ]
  let sorted = [];
  for (let key in sortObject) {
    // Searches the refArray for the linkKey, and returns the intended index
    let index = reference.find((item) => item[linkKey] === key)[orderKey];
    // Places the sortObject's value in the correct index of the 'sorted' Array
    sorted[parseInt(index)] = [key, sortObject[key]];
  };

  // Return an object, created from previous 'sorted' Array
  return sorted.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
};

offerings = sortObjectFromArray(subgroup, offerings, 'orderNumber', 'name');

console.log(offerings);
```